# C# Inheritance, new modifier and generics

Tags: c#, linq, generics, inheritance, name-hiding

I'm having a hard trying to find to correct approach to this :

My data structures :

```
public abstract class Flow
{
    public virtual double Value { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime Time { get; set; }
}

public class InboundFlow : Flow
{
}

public class OutboundFlow : Flow
{
}
```

My business objects containing collections of these data structures

```
public abstract class Fluent
{
    public virtual IList<Flow> FlowCollection { get; set; }
    public virtual double InitialBaseflow { get; set; }
}

public class Affluent : Fluent
{
    public new virtual IList<InboundFlow> FlowCollection { get; set; }
}

public class Effluent : Fluent
{
    public new virtual IList<OutboundFlow> FlowCollection { get; set; }
}
```

The generic method I'm trying to use :

```
private static void FindInitialBaseflow<T>(ref T fluent) where T : Fluent
    {
        var linqFluent = fluent;

        var flows = linqFluent.FlowCollection.ToList().FindAll(
                    flow =>
                    flow.Time >= SOME_DATE &&
                    flow.Time < SOME_OTHER_DATE);
        var initialBaseflow = flows.Average(flow => flow.Value);
        fluent.InitialBaseflow = Math.Round(initialBaseflow, 5);  
    }
```

My problem is that calling "linqfluent.FlowCollection" in the linq method calls for the **base class Fluent's FlowCollection**, which is null.

How can I force the use of the child's property instead? Thanks!

Comment: `new` overwrites the property with a new version, you'd need to override it. But then you'd have problems with covariance.

Comment: can you show me how you make the call to FindInitialBaseflow ?? Does FindInitialBaseflow< Affluent >(ref affluentobject)  make the call to base class collection..

Comment: @Ashley John : FindInitialBaseflow(ref affluent) and affluent is of Affluent type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the collection within `Fluent` generic so that the classes that inherit from it can specify the type:

```
public class Fluent<T>
    where T : Flow
{
    public IList<T> FlowCollection { get; set; }
    public double InitialBaseflow { get; set; }
}
```

Once you have that you don't even need sub classes of `Flow`, you can just make it concrete.

Your use of it would be easily modified to fit this model:

```
private static void FindInitialBaseflow<T>(Fluent<T> fluent) 
    where T : Flow
{
    var linqFluent = fluent;

    var flows = linqFluent.FlowCollection.Where(
                flow =>
                flow.Time >= SOME_DATE &&
                flow.Time < SOME_OTHER_DATE);
    var initialBaseflow = flows.Average(flow => flow.Value);
    fluent.InitialBaseflow = Math.Round(initialBaseflow, 5);
}
```

Also note that since you're not setting `fluent` in this method, there is no need to pass it by reference.  It's already a class, so it *is* itself a reference; mutations of the referenced object will be observed by the caller.

Answer (score -1):

Generics are the wrong tool.  You should using polymorphism to ensure the correct implementation is called based on the type.

For example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    public abstract class Flow
    {
        public virtual double Value { get { return new Random().Next() ; } }//these values are just for demonstration purposes
        public virtual DateTime Time
        {
            get
            {
                return DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public class InboundFlow : Flow
    {
    }

    public class OutboundFlow : Flow
    {
    }

    public abstract class Fluent
    {
        IList<Flow> _flowCollection;
        public virtual IList<Flow> FlowCollection
        {
            get { return _flowCollection; }
            set { _flowCollection = value; }
        }

        private double _initialBaseflow;
        public virtual double InitialBaseflow
        {
            get { return _initialBaseflow; }
            set { _initialBaseflow = value; }
        }

        public Fluent()
        {
            FlowCollection = new List<Flow>();
        }
    }

    public class Affluent : Fluent
    {
        //public new virtual IList<InboundFlow> FlowCollection { get; set; }//Keep the property polymorphic

        public Affluent()
        {
            FlowCollection = new List<Flow>();
        }
    }

    public class Effluent : Fluent
    {
        //public new virtual IList<OutboundFlow> FlowCollection { get; set; }

        public Effluent()
        {
            FlowCollection = new List<Flow>();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        public static DateTime SOME_DATE { get { return DateTime.MinValue; } }
        public static DateTime SOME_OTHER_DATE { get { return DateTime.Now; } }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inbound = new InboundFlow();
            var inbound2 = new InboundFlow();
            var outbound = new OutboundFlow();
            var a = new Affluent();            
            a.FlowCollection.Add(inbound);
            a.FlowCollection.Add(inbound2);
            FindInitialBaseflow(a);
        }

        private static void FindInitialBaseflow(Fluent fluent)
        {
            var linqFluent = fluent;

            var flows = linqFluent.FlowCollection.ToList().FindAll(
                        flow =>
                        flow.Time >= SOME_DATE &&
                        flow.Time < SOME_OTHER_DATE);
            var initialBaseflow = flows.Average(flow => flow.Value);
            fluent.InitialBaseflow = Math.Round(initialBaseflow, 5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But the properties in the sub-types hide the `FlowCollection` property, they don't override it, so in this case you're not getting polymorphic behavior.  This is the problem the OP was observing with his code, and your change doesn't alter that behavior.

Comment: @Servy - Just because the OP did not setup his properties correctly does not mean he can't or shouldn't use polymorphism.  Generics are not good for polymorphic behavior which is what the OP asked for.

Comment: You'll need to show him how to "set up his properties correctly" if you want this to be an answer.  Note that his properties do not all resolve to the same type.  Polymorphic behavior would *require* all of the collections to be of the same compile time type.  Since that isn't possible, generics are clearly the way to go.  If you can show a polymorphic solution *that actually works*, instead of one with the *exact same problem as the OP's code* then by all means, I'd love to see it.

Comment: Generics help me eliminate code duplication as I must do the same calculations for Affluent and Effluent properties

Comment: @PhillyQc - To me that has code smell.  I suggest adding new behavior to the children Affluent/Effluent as opposed to hiding the base implementations and killing polymorphism.

Comment: I see this as code smell.  `Affluent` and `Effluent` add nothing.  They don't add the constraint of a specific type of `Flow`, as the OP intended, nor do they modify any behavior (or really have any meaningful outlet to modify any behavior).  The code the OP would indicate that it's important to have collections typed to derived instances of `Flow`, rather than `Flow` itself.

Comment: @Servy - I disagree.  The OP is trying to achieve polymorphism *because* he removed it...that does not make sense IMO. Like I stated earlier, new behavior should be added here.  That new behavior (YET to be defined) gives Affluent/Effluent meaning.

Comment: As I have outlined above, Affluent and Effluent are business objects, they have several identical properties that need to be calculated the same way, but they also have their own specific properties. Inbound and outbound flows are also treated differently in business logic. Anyway guys thanks for the response, but I don't think it's the right place for a design debate over a partial portion of code.

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey The code in the OP makes it clear that the specific behavior defined in those two classes is that all of the `Flow` objects must be of a specific type more derived than `Flow`, i.e. `InBoundFlow`.  You removed that added functionality entirely.  Before you just choose to remove that feature, they had meaning.  Because you removed it, they now no longer have meaning (and the purpose they served is not fulfilled through other means, unlike my example where I removed the classes but filled the purpose they served.).

Comment: @PhillyQc - Agreed.  Good luck!  Glad you found something that works for you.